# Section header on top of UISearchBar on iOS 8. Works on iOS 9

Tags: ios8, xcode7, ios9, uisearchcontroller

Using UISearchController to add filtering to a UITableView.  The section header overlaps with the search bar on iOS 8 using Xcode 7.  This looks good in iOS 9.  What workaround can I get in place so iOS 8 looks like the iOS 9 version?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    self.definesPresentationContext = true
    self.searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

    tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

[image: UITableView with sections and index on iOS 8 Simulator]

Comment: I'm currently having the same issue - did you ever find a fix?

Comment: @Harry I had luck with calling ``sizeToFit()`` on the ``searchBar`` before setting it as the ``tableHeaderView``

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Made the change to be:

```
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    self.searchController.definesPresentationContext = true
    self.searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController.searchBar;
    tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

So setting the definesPresentationContext on the searchController, not the view controller.

Comment: How putting the seachBar in titleView instead of tableHeaderView solved the problem here? It's not really solving the issue...

Answer (score 1):

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 44)];
[self.tableView.tableHeaderView addSubview:self.searchController.searchBar];
```

Create a new UIView and add searchBar as a subview, then set the tableView's header view to the new created view will solve the issue.